# How to get string with fullpath of files for copy files

Tags: c#, file, directory, copying

I have directories (for example, 5555555) where stored files (files named "directory-date", for example 555555-181118). I get collection List  with  Directory.GetFiles(string) help. How I can get full pathways of files and copy these files to another directory?

```
public static List<string[]> FindingDataDevice(List<string> selectedDevices, string pathData, DateTime DateStartWeek)
{
    var dateTime = String.Format("{0:yyMMdd}", DateStartWeek);
    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(pathData).Where(r => selectedDevices.Any(t => r.Contains(t))).ToList();
    var fileList = folders.Select(r => Directory.GetFiles(r, "*-"+ dateTime + "*")).ToList();
    return fileList;
    }
```

Comment: you should narrow down your question a bit more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.
The function now returns a list with the file names (fullpath).

```
public static List<string> FindingDataDevice(List<string> selectedDevices, string pathData, DateTime DateStartWeek)
{
    var dateTime = String.Format("{0:yyMMdd}", DateStartWeek);
    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(pathData).Where(r => selectedDevices.Any(t => r.Contains(t))).ToList();
    return folders.Select(r => Directory.GetFiles(r, "*-" + dateTime + "*"))
            .Where(f => f.Length > 0)
            .SelectMany(f => f)
            .ToList();
}
```